# Simple Tensorflow 2 classifier won't learn

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

It's a simple model architecture based on [this tutorial](https://github.com/dragen1860/TensorFlow-2.x-Tutorials/tree/master/01-TF2.0-Overview). The dataset would look like this, although in 10 dimensions:
[image]

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras import layers, optimizers
from sklearn.datasets import make_blobs

def pre_processing(inputs, targets):
    inputs = tf.cast(inputs, tf.float32)
    targets = tf.cast(targets, tf.int64)
    return inputs, targets

def get_data():
    inputs, targets = make_blobs(n_samples=1000, n_features=10, centers=7, cluster_std=1)
    data = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((inputs, targets))
    data = data.map(pre_processing)
    data = data.take(count=1000).shuffle(buffer_size=1000).batch(batch_size=256)
    return data

model = Sequential([
    layers.Dense(8, input_shape=(10,), activation='relu'),
    layers.Dense(16, activation='relu'),
    layers.Dense(32, activation='relu'),
    layers.Dense(7)])

@tf.function
def compute_loss(logits, labels):
    return tf.reduce_mean(
        tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(
            logits=logits, labels=labels))

@tf.function
def compute_accuracy(logits, labels):
    predictions = tf.argmax(logits, axis=1)
    return tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(tf.equal(predictions, labels), tf.float32))

@tf.function
def train_step(model, optim, x, y):
    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
        logits = model(x)
        loss = compute_loss(logits, y)

    grads = tape.gradient(loss, model.trainable_variables)
    optim.apply_gradients(zip(grads, model.trainable_variables))

    accuracy = compute_accuracy(logits, y)
    return loss, accuracy

def train(epochs, model, optim):
    train_ds = get_data()

    loss = 0.
    acc = 0.

    for step, (x, y) in enumerate(train_ds):
        loss, acc = train_step(model, optim, x, y)

        if step % 500 == 0:
            print(f'Epoch {epochs} loss {loss.numpy()} acc {acc.numpy()}')

    return loss, acc

optim = optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=1e-6)

for epoch in range(100):
    loss, accuracy = train(epoch, model, optim)
```

```
Epoch 85 loss 2.530677080154419 acc 0.140625
Epoch 86 loss 3.3184046745300293 acc 0.0
Epoch 87 loss 3.138179063796997 acc 0.30078125
Epoch 88 loss 3.7781732082366943 acc 0.0
Epoch 89 loss 3.4101686477661133 acc 0.14453125
Epoch 90 loss 2.2888522148132324 acc 0.13671875
Epoch 91 loss 5.993691444396973 acc 0.16015625
```

What have I done wrong?

Comment: Looks unnecessarily complicated; since you do use what is actually a Keras model, I suggest you first stick to it (i.e. use `model.fit` etc instead of the low-level Tensorflow API), except of course if you use this as a learning exercise for TF

Comment: I know how to use `keras`, it's time to move on to something new.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems in your code:

- The first one is that you are generating a new training dataset in each epoch (see first line of `train` function, i.e. `get_data` function is called in each epoch). Since you are using [`sklearn.datasets.make_blobs`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.datasets.make_blobs.html) function to generate data clusters, there is no guarantee that the generated data clusters between different calls follow the same distribution and/or label mapping. Therefore, the best thing the model could do in each epoch on a completely different dataset is just a random guess (hence, the average 1/7 ~= 0.14 accuracy you see in the results). To resolve this problem, take the data generation out of `train` function (i.e. generate the data at global level once by calling `get_data` function), and then pass the generated data to `train` function as an argument in each epoch.
- The second problem is that you are using a very low learning rate, i.e. 1e-6, for the optimizer; therefore, the model is stuck and effectively not training at all. Instead, use the default learning rate for Adam optimizer, i.e. 1e-3, and change it only as needed (e.g. based on the results of experiments you perform).

Comment: You're right. That was a rookie mistake that had nothing to do with Tensorflow. I was just fetching a new dataset with every call to `get_data()`.